# Get Parent Container Text field in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a parent container which has a ViewPager inside it. I inflate the ViewPager in a ViewPagerAdapter to set a slider. Apart from moving the slider, I require an reference to ViewPager parent so that I can populate a text field in it.

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
            false);
```

How can I get reference to the text field in parent container from itemView?

Complete code -

```
View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
            false);

    View fragmentView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first_scroll_view, container, false);

    // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
    txtrank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
    txtcountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
    //txtpopulation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);

    txtpopulation=(TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.population);


    // Capture position and set to the TextViews
    txtrank.setText(rank[position]);
    txtcountry.setText(country[position]);

    System.out.println(population[position]);
    txtpopulation.setText(population[position]);


    // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
    imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
    // Capture position and set to the ImageView
    imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);

    // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
```

Comment: Why don't you inflate directly the parent of ViewPager and then in that inflated view call `findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id)` ?

Comment: I tried that, but it was not able to set the text field of the parent container. For example if the ViewPager is inside a fragment, on horizontal scroll, I want to update the counter in the parent fragment.  -txtpopulation=(TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.population); txtpopulation.setText(population[position]);

Comment: You're doing something really strange then. Can you share more code? Specifically the part where you update that text view

Comment: did that, have added code to the question

Comment: Strangely - System.out.println(txtpopulation.getText()); gives me the current text but am unable to set Text..
        txtpopulation.setText("Amit");

Comment: I was really doing some thing stupid. I am able to set text from within the fragment_first_scroll_view, but not from the child java code.

Comment: I'm sorry for my gone. If you solve your issue I'm happy. And consider write it as an answer to your question.

Comment: @amit_pandey It'll help if you answer your own question. Have a similar problem.

Comment: I am trying to figure it out. Going through books to see how we can delegate or update parent view or call their functions. Basically the idea is to call a function with parameter in the parent fragment to update the display. Would answer once resolved, or hopefully someone can expedite it.